# Communication to parallel (not cascade) 74hc595 over common bus lines

Tags: stm32, shift-register, 74hc595

PFA the hardware design. I am trying to send data to parallel (not cascade) 74hc595 over common bus lines from CD4094B. I am sending 16 bits to place first 8 bits in 74hc595(1) and second bits in 74hc595(2). But I am getting same 8 bits (10101010) on both 74hc595 devices.

Could you please let me know how to send 16 bits such that first 8 bits should place in first 74hc595 and second 8 bits should place in second 74hc595. Please find the code snippet below and let me know if I am missing anything.

```
CODE::    
----------    
uint8_t test[16] = {1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0};    
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_11, GPIO_PIN_SET); // CD4094 OE    
for (int bit=0; bit<16; bit++)    
{    
   HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_10, GPIO_PIN_RESET);  //CD4094 STROBE    
   output = test[bit] & 1;    
   if (output)
   {    
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_2, GPIO_PIN_SET); //CD4094 DATA
   } 
   else    
   {
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_2, GPIO_PIN_RESET); //CD4094 DATA     
   }
   HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_0, GPIO_PIN_RESET); //CD4094 CLOCK    
   HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_0, GPIO_PIN_SET);          
   HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_10, GPIO_PIN_SET); // CD4094 STROBE    
   HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_12, GPIO_PIN_RESET); // 74hc595 CLOCK

   HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_12, GPIO_PIN_SET);     
}    
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_RESET); // 74hc595 OE    
HAL_Delay(3000);    
HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_SET);    
HAL_Delay(3000);
```

Thanks,

Balu[image: PCB Schematic]

Thanks for the reply. Please find the full schematic.[image: PCB full schematic-1]
[image: PCB full schematic-2]

Comment: Based on the block diagram, the 74HC595 chips share the same clock and data pins, so there is no way to send different data to both chips. Please provide more details such as schematics in case the block diagram does not contain the necessary info.

Comment: We have changed the hardware design and it is working as expected. Thanks for your help and support,

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways I can think of to do this, all of which require an alteration to your present hardware. Depending on exactly where any spare pins or wires are, one scheme might require less alteration than the others, so would be preferable.

1. The usual way 595's are used, run serial out of one to serial in of the next. It all just happens then when you clock 16 bits through the pair.
2. Run each 595 serial data in from a separate data line. Clock the data out of the MCU as eight 2-bit words, one bit to each of the two parallel 595's
3. The 595 also has a latch input. For driving simplicity this is often connected to the shift clock, but it can be used separately. Send clock and a single data line to both 595 clock and serial data inputs, but drive the latch signal from separate MCU output pins. Clock out your 16 bits of data, driving the latch to the first 595 after 8 clocks, and the latch to the second after all 16 clocks. It can help to think of the latch input as a not_chip_select C̅S̅.

Answer (score -1):

Think your goal is the exact way a serial connection of 74HC595 is supposed to work.

Connect the two chips in serial where the second chip's input is connected to the first chip's Q(H)' output (pin9).

Then feed all 16 bits of your data into the first chip and the first 8-bits will flow right into your second chip. And the last 8-bits will remain in the first chip.

This is the only way (and how the chips were designed)

Comment: It's not the only way, check out the three ways in my answer

Comment: Oh, I'm sure you can even imagine more but, to take full advantage of the 74HC595 design, the recommendation in the App notes and the tens-of-thousands of published examples all use the method I described.  But feel free to look for exceptions and suggest non-standard solutions to a very basic functionality.